# Space above text that is next to a image

Tags: html, css

[image]As you can see. I have space above header 3, I want it to be inline with the image itself.

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="content"><img src="img/user_avatar.jpg" width="100" height="101" /><h3>Jonas Hitler</h3></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap{
     display: inline-block;  
     border:1px solid; 
     border-radius:8px; 
     background-color:#fff; 
     padding:10px; 
     width:800px;
     }


.content{font-family:"Segoe UI"}
.content img, .content h3 { float: left;}
.content img {border:1px solid; border-radius:8px; margin-right: 15px;}
.content h3 {font-size: 22px;}
.content h3 span { font-size: 14px; }
```

Comment: Looks fine on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NFfe5/90/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the default stylesheet applied by the user agent. you could reset that by `margin: 0;` as follows:

```css
.content h3 {font-size: 22px; margin: 0;}
```

**[Online Demo](http://jsbin.com/bufubosi/1/edit)**

User agents apply some default styles to the HTML elements. For instance they apply a top and bottom `margin` on the heading elements such as `<h3>`.

*As Google Chrome sets `-webkit-margin-before: 1em;` and `-webkit-margin-after: 1em;`*.

Most web developers use some CSS declarations at the top of the stylesheet called **[CSS Reset](http://www.cssreset.com/)** to reset the user agent default styles.

Whether to use a tiny reset:

```css
* { padding:0; margin: 0;}
```

Or a [well-known version](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) by CSS legendary Eric Meyer.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `margin-top: 0px;`

```
.content h3 {font-size: 22px;  margin-top: 0px;}
```

Header tags have margin applied by browsers, you are essentially resetting this style.

You should consider using a [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) in future.

See this pen. 
http://codepen.io/JRKyte/pen/akcbF

Answer (score 0):

The `h3` has a margin by default. Just add `margin-top:0;` to the h3 and there you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/rhUb7/

Answer (score 0):

If you set both elements to inline-block they will set side but side and you have more control than when floating the item - just remember to remove any white space between tags.. Just change the top margin to 0, and you don't need any unit when the value is 0.

```
.content > img, .content > h3 { display: inline-block; margin-top: 0; vertical-align: top;}
```