# Extra spacing on CSS Menu

Tags: css, menu, alignment, padding

I'm having a weird problem with my CSS menu. There is a huge space above the links.

I tried everything from removing all the margin and padding settings from the css and still nothing. The only way I can remove the extra spacing is to delete all the li.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/3dB7v/

```
<div id="test_nav">
    <div id="test_subnav">
        <ul id="test_ul">
            <li><a href="#" target="">Test 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="">Test 2</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <asp:panel id="pnlUpdateDate" cssclass="UpdateDate" runat="server">Last Update: 11-26-2013</asp:panel>
</div


#test_nav
{
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}

#pnlUpdateDate
{
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}

#test_subnav
{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#test_ul li
{
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1001;
    b1order: 1px dashed orange;
}

#test_ul li ul
{
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#test_ul > li
{
    float: left;
    padding: 3px; /* padding-top: 3px;  padding-bottom: 3px; */
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;
}

#test_ul > li > a, #test_ul > li > span
{
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    margin: 0 3px 0 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#test_ul > li > span
{
    cursor: default;
}

#test_ul > li:hover > a, #test_ul > li.active > a
{
    color: Red;
}

#test_ul > li:hover > a:active
{
    color: #3B96B6;
}

#test_ul > li:hover > span
{
    color: #3B96B6;
}
```

Comment: Check out my answer to avoid future problems like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That space belongs to the default margins of the `ul#test_ul` element applied by the useragent.

You should reset the default stylesheet applied by user agent on the list element, as follows:

```css
ul#test_ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

You can refer to **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016764/space-above-text-that-is-next-to-a-image/22016844#22016844)** for further details:

> User agents apply some default styles to the HTML elements. For
>   instance they apply a top and bottom margin on the `<p>`, `<ul>`, ... elements.
>
> As Google Chrome sets `-webkit-margin-before: 1em;` and `-webkit-margin-after: 1em;`.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/3dB7v/1/)**

It's better to **[reset](http://www.cssreset.com/)** user agent stylesheet before any author stylesheet to prevent unexpected issues.

Comment: Any reason to specify the element type along with the ID?

Comment: @ZachSaucier Just To direct the OP to the certain element.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the margin and padding from the `ul` element.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way would be `* { padding:0; margin:0; }`

What you are seeing is the **browser default styles**. Consider locating a "reset" stylesheet and always applying it first before any other styles. I like this one: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

*Address the problem, not the symptoms.* You'll run into this all the time if you don't. Each browsers *default* styles are different. Zeroing them all out is the only way to get consistency throughout.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add this to your CSS:

```
#test_ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```