# HTML : P Tag height exceeding parent DIV tag height

Tags: php, css, html

I am having a HTML script as follows:

```
<DIV id="body_area">
    <TABLE> SOME cODE INSIE TABLE...</TABLE>
</DIV>
<DIV id="foot">
    <P>&copy;Copyright/2014</P>
</DIV>
```

CSS for abve code:

```
#body_area{
    background:yellow;
}
#foot{
    background:red;
    height:20px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border:0px;
}
#foot p{
    color:white;
//  height:20px;
    line-height:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-style:regular;
    font-size:16px;
    padding:0px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    border:0px;
}
```

I am getting a white gap/space of about 20px between `#body_area` & `#foot`, I tried replacing `<P></P>` bu `<i></i>` and the space/white band between the two `div` vanishes. How can I limit height of `P` tag with in its parent `DIV`? I tried applying `height:20px;` explicitly to the `P` tag but no effect....

Regards.

Comment: That's probably because of the [user agent stylesheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016764/space-above-text-that-is-next-to-a-image/22016844#22016844). Try to reset the default styles on `<p>` element by `margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;` at the very beginning of author stylesheet (your own CSS file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a JSFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/9rTFK/

There are 2 problems in the `#foot p` rule, you cannot comment with `//` in CSS, you'll need to do `/*height: 20px*/`, otherwise browser will use this rule.

About your space problem, just add:

```
margin:0
```

To the  `#foot p` CSS rule

Comment: Right on both counts. I wish it were possible to upvote twice.

Answer (score 0):

kindly consider replacing

- <DIV id="body_area"> with <[main](http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/html5_main_tag.php)> tag
   and <DIV
  id="foot"> with <[footer](http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/html5_footer_tag.php)> tag

why semantic markup is important?
because web machines understand it, thus is good for SEO

Comment: You may have a point, but without seeing all of the OP's HTML, you won't know if that is the intended meaning. And this doesn't address the OP's problem at all.